# Javascript. If array has 3 odds in a row, print "odd". if array has 3 evens in a row - print "even"

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new to javascript and I'm looking for some help with the following algorithm.

If array has 3 odd numbers in a row, print "odd". if array has 3 even number in a row - print "even".

```
function oddsAndEvens (arr) {

    for(i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i]%2==0 && arr[i+1]%2==0 &&  arr[i+2]%2==0) { 
        console.log("even");
        }
       if(arr[i]%2!=0 && arr[i+1]%2!=0 &&  arr[i+2]%2!=0) {
       console.log("odd");
        }
    }
}
```

oddsAndEvens ([2,4,6]);

Comment: What is expected result if array contains two odd numbers and one even number? Or, is input only three odd numbers or three even numbers?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.every()`. You could also include check if element of array is, for example `7.5`

```js
var oddsAndEvens = (arr) => arr.every(n => n % 2 === 0) && "even" 
    || arr.every(n => n % 2 != 0) && "odd";

console.log(oddsAndEvens([2, 4, 5])
           , oddsAndEvens([33, 99, 7])
           , oddsAndEvens([7.5, 4, 6]));
```

Comment: This is wrong as `n % 1` is true for every number. Try [2,4,5] - it returns odd which is not what OP need. You should change `n % 1 === 1` to `n % 2 != 0` Strict comparision operator is not needed because result is always integer. `n % 2 == 0` is ok for even.

Comment: @instead Good catch. Corrected Answer using the suggested approach

Answer (score 0):

What You need is a counter for odd and event numbers. Below function will count them all and if there are 3 or more matches, then it prints in console log "odd" OR/AND "even". Works for array of any size.

```
function oddsAndEvens (arr) {
    var odd_count = 0,
        even_count = 0;

    for(i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        if(arr[i]%2==0) {
            event_count ++;

        }else if(arr[i]%2!=0){
            odd_count ++;
        }

    }

    if(even_count >= 3){
        console.log('even');
    }

    if(odd_count >= 3){
        console.log('odd');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure you have 3 **defined** values first. You need to add:

```
if(arr[i] && arr[i+1] && arr[i+2]) { }
```

full code:

```js
function oddsAndEvens (arr) {
  for(i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] && arr[i+1] && arr[i+2]) {
        if(arr[i]%2==0 && arr[i+1]%2==0 &&  arr[i+2]%2==0) { 
        console.log("even");
        }
        if(arr[i]%2!=0 && arr[i+1]%2!=0 &&  arr[i+2]%2!=0) {
        console.log("odd");
        }
 }
  }
}
oddsAndEvens([1,3]); /* nothing. no 3 defined values in a row */
oddsAndEvens([1,3,7]); /* odd */
oddsAndEvens([2,2,8]); /* even */
oddsAndEvens([1,3,1, 9]); /* odd, odd */
```